# Adding BOTH Mail and SMS/MMS delegates to class type

Tags: ios, swift, class, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have a simple app. It emails and SMS/MMS a screenshot.

Since I have two buttons that each execute two different functions - (1) screenshot then email; and (2) screenshot then SMS/MMS, I need to add these to my `class` in my code.

Currently ...

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI


class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
```

How can I add `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` to my above class statement?

I think I need to as I have functions that send Email and SMS/MMS.

Apologies for my language description, I'm very new :)

Comment: Just add it! No problem.

Comment: ya you can use the both in same class , where you struck

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But I get an error when I run the code - **'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate**

Comment: Oddly enough, when I omit `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`, from the class line, my code to send a SMS still builds without a hitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also check this link : [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983222/xcode-cannot-adopt-protocol)

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func sendText(sender: UIButton) {
    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.body = "Message Body"
        controller.recipients = [phoneNumber.text]
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


   func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    //... handle sms screen actions
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}

 @IBAction func sendMail(sender: UIButton)
 {
    let mailClass:AnyClass?  =NSClassFromString("MFMailComposeViewController")
   if(mailClass != nil)
   {
    if((mailClass?.canSendMail()) != nil)
    {
      displayComposerSheet()
    }
  }

  func displayComposerSheet()
  {
   let picker: MFMailComposeViewController=MFMailComposeViewController()
   picker.mailComposeDelegate=self;
   picker .setSubject("Test")
   picker.setMessageBody("Mail Sharing !", isHTML: true)
   let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "images.jpg")!)!
   picker.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "images.png")
   self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }


  func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    default:
        break
    }
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }


 }
```

Comment: I tried to add it, but I get the error message: **'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate**

Comment: All good now. Followed your link and now I understand the method, Thanks